# Is there a perticular format for sigma.js compatible json file ?

Tags: c++, json, sigma.js

Im trying to generate a json file which should be compatible with sigma.js to plot the graph  ? can i know in what format it should be ? in C++.

Comment: sigma.js documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The sigma.js json format, derived from the [sigma.js wiki](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki), consists of an array of *edges* and an array of *nodes*.

An *edge* has three string properties:

- *id* is a unique identifier for this edge), and
- *source*, *target* are *ids* for nodes.

A *node* has the properties:

- *id* is a unique identifier for this node,
- *label* is an optional text displayed along with the node,
- *x*, *y* are coordinates in the plane (can be floating-point),
- *color* is an optional [CSS color specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-color), and
- *size* is a logical size comparable to other edge sizes.

In summary, only *color* and *label* are optional, and only *x*, *y* and *size* are numbers, the rest are strings. Even when using automatic layout generators (e.g. the ForceAtlas2 plugin), it is necessary to specify initial *x* and *y*, and even if all nodes have the same size, *size* must be specified. (This is not mentioned in the docs, but it can be confirmed experimentally.)

This is an abbreviated excerpt from the GitHub sample [arctic.json](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/data/arctic.json):

```
{
  "edges": [
    {
      "source": "473",
      "target": "313",
      "id": "6432"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "262",
      "label": "Sciences De La Terre",
      "x": 1412.2230224609,
      "y": -2.0559763908386,
      "size": 8.540210723877
      "color": "rgb(255,204,102)",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```